# Intellisense for asp-controller or asp-action in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core, intellisense

I have just installed latest version of VS 2017 with asp.net core 2. The tag helpers intellisense works for `asp-for="FirstName"` (where FirstName is a property of my Model), but it does not work for something like `asp-controller ="..."` or `asp-action="..."`.

Is there any way (for example an Extension) to provide intellisense for controller/action... names to avoid manual typing of them?

**Update** (More info):

for example, if you have a model named Customer as:

```
public class Customer
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Code { get; set; }
}
```

and following razor code in your Index.cshtml:

```
@{ var myVar = "abc";}
<input type="text" asp-for="@myVar" />

<label asp-for="FirstName">Name:</label>
<input type="text" asp-for="FirstName" />

<a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="About">About</a>
```

you will have intellisense for FirstName in `asp-for="Firs..."`, but not for similar properties `asp-controller="Hom...` or `asp-action="Abou..."` while both of them are purple and bold (as TagHelpers).

Comment: Where are you trying to apply those attributes? To which element?

Comment: @RicardoPeres for example to `asp-controller` and `asp-action` in `<a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="About">About</a>`. I updated the post, please check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible, essentially because finding controllers - and, therefore, actions - is tricky. A controller can be a lot of things:

- A class that inherits from BaseController
- A POCO class with the Controller suffix
- Other supplied by some conventions
- Other defined at runtime

Comment: Although i think that the Visual Studio or an Extension can at least provide the list of normal controllers like those defined as `HomeController : Controller` which have the "Controller" suffix and/or inherited from `Controller` or `BaseController`. Even if it is not complete in some (rare) cases, it will be helpfull and prevent some typo mistakes...

Comment: ReSharper does it just fine, so obviously it can be done.

Comment: Rider does it i have tested right now